# Finding the key whose value is the lowest value in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, key, min

I'm trying to come up with an efficient way to return a key in my `HashMap` that has the lowest value in datastructure. Is there a quick and efficient way to do this besides looping through the entire `HashMap`?

For example, if I have a hashmap that looks like this:

```
1: 200
3: 400
5: 1
```

I want to return the key, 5.

Comment: what does "lowest value" mean?

Comment: you'll need to edit it further, a HashMap in java has the form `new HashMap<keytype, valuetype>()`. Did you mean it's a HashMap<Integer,Integer>`? If so, a HashMap might not be the data structure you want to be using.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you mean OP should not be using `HashMap` if it is `Integer -> Integer` map? Why?

Comment: I mean they *might* not be using the optimal data structure, especially if they also need to search through the key space. Without additional information, not committing one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned `HashMap` itself does not provide this.

So your options are to either compute it on-demand or pre-compute.

To compute it on-demand, you would iterate the `HashMap.entrySet()`

Depending on the size of the map, frequency of its change and frequency of requiring the `key-with-lowest-value`, pre-computing (caching) may be more efficient. Something as follows:

```
class HashMapWithLowestValueCached<K, V extends Comparable> extends HashMap<K, V> {    
    V lowestValue;
    K lowestValueKey;    
    void put(K k, V v) {
      if (v.compareTo(lowestValue) < 0) {
        lowestValue = v; 
        lowestValueKey = k;
      }
      super.put(k, v);
    }
    K lowestValueKey () { return lowestValueKey; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you have to loop over all the keys in a `HashMap` to find the smallest. If this is an important operation, you're better off using a `SortedMap`, for instance `TreeMap`, which keeps its elements in sorted order, and then you can simply call [`firstKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#firstKey%28%29) to find the lowest key.

Comment: The OP wanted the key with the lowest **value**, not the lowest key value.

Comment: He's asking for the lowest value, not key.

Comment: @maba: You are correct. I want the key with the lowest value.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no quick and efficient way of doing that - you need to loop through the entire hash map. The reason for it is that the keys and values in hash maps do not observe any particular order.

Comment: As mentioned in some other answers, OP is looking for key with lowest value, not the lowest key.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way of doing this. You need to iterate over all the elements in the HashMap to find the one with the lowest value.

The reason why we have different kinds of storage is that they support different kinds of operations with different efficiency. HashMap is not designed to retrieve elements efficienctly based on their value. The kind of storage class you need for this will depend on what other operations you need to be able to do quickly. Assuming that you probably also want to be able to retrieve items quickly based on their key, the following might work:

1. Write a wrapper around your HashMap that keeps track of all the elements being added to it, and remembers which oneis the smallest. This is really only useful if retriving the smalls is the only way you need to access by value.
2. Store all your data twice - once in a HashMap and once in a data structure that sorts by value - for example, a SortedMap with key and value reversed.
3. If you find you don't need to retrieve by key, just reverse key and value.

Answer (score 1):

No, because otherwise there would exist a sorting algorithm in O(n log n) (probabilistic, though): add all elements to the hash map, than extract the lowest one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
//create hashmap  
HashMap<Integer, String> yourHashmap = new HashMap<>();
//add your values here
yourHashmap.put(1,"200");
yourHashmap.put(3,"400");
yourHashmap.put(5,"1");
        
//then create empty arraylist
ArrayList<Integer> listDuplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        
//filing the empty arraylist with all id's from duplicateHashmap
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : yourHashmap.entrySet()) {
    listDuplicates.add(entry.getKey());
}
        
//Ordering the numbers
Collections.sort(listDuplicates);
        
for (Integer num : listDuplicates) {
    int id = num; //entry
    String number2 = duplicateHashmap.get(num);//value
    System.out.println("lowest value = "+id+" : "+number2);
    //breaking here because we've found the lowest value...
    break;          
}
```